# Copy file from /boot partition

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I am trying to copy a file from the boot directory for a rasbian image. I would like add this file once to the sd card and not have to run raspbian to manually add this file (preferable, write a script for raspbian to copy on startup).

I have a custom configuration file that I would like to copy over during startup, preferably into /home/pi. I put the sd card into my computer and dropped the file into the boot directory.

The issue is that the file isnt visible in /boot when I boot up the pi and ssh into it. I am putting a file named custom-configuration.txt into the /boot directory (next to wpa_supplicant and ssh files).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I know I can put the file in there manually but I would like to not have to ssh in to do so, would like to just drop it onto the sd card after writing the image with etcher on osx as I have to do this many time and the configuration file will be different for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You drop the file `custom-configuration.txt` to the `boot` directory on the SD Card when it is attached to your computer. After booting the SD Card in a Raspberry Pi you should find this file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ls -l /boot/custom-configuration.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Apr 29 20:39 /boot/custom-configuration.txt
```

The only reason I can figure why the file `custom-configuration.txt` isn't present is that it isn't the same `boot` directory than you used on the computer.

For testing try the other way. First delete `boot/custom-configuration.txt` on the computer. Then boot the SD Card in the RasPi and create the file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo touch /boot/custom-configuration.txt
```

Then look if you find it on the computer.

**Update** from a comment
*@timmyg13* found the reason for the issue and wrote:

> I just realized that I was running ssh pi@raspberrypi.local to connect but I was actually connecting to a separate raspberry pi running elsewhere on my network - so obviously the files weren't there.

Comment: I tried this out and I dont see it under either circumstance. All the files are exactly the same (a lot of .dtb, .dat, .elf files) but no new file I create is visible from the computer that I wrote directly from the pi nor on the pi that I wrote directly onto the sd card from my computer.

Comment: seems like according to this https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/mount-raspberry-pi-sd-card-on-mac-read-only-osxfuse-and-ext4fuse I can do it all via the SD card. I would prefer to not have to mount, etc. and just be able to drop it in the boot directory (along with the wpa_supplicant) and have a script move it over (and remove it from /boot) on startup

Comment: Ahh - I just realized that I was running `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` to connect but I was actually connecting to a separate raspberry pi running elsewhere on my network - so obviously the files weren't there. Sorry!

Comment: @timmyg13 Thanks for feedback :-) I have added the reason to the answer.